# How to look for a certain part in a string and only keep that part

Tags: r

What is the cleanest way of finding for example the string ": [1-9]*" and only keeping that part?

You can work with regexec to get the starting points, but isn't there a cleaner way just to get immediately the value?

For example:

```
test <- c("surface area: 458", "bedrooms: 1", "whatever")
regexec(": [1-9]*", test)
```

How do I get immediately just

```
c(": 458",": 1", NA )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(test, ":.*")
#[1] ": 458" ": 1"   NA
```

Or for a faster approach `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_first_regex(test, ":.*")
#[1] ": 458" ": 1"   NA
```

If you need the keep the values of the one that doesn't have the match

```
gsub(".*(:.*)", "\\1", test)
#[1] ": 458"    ": 1"      "whatever"
```

Comment: Thanks. Isn't it strange that this is not in the standard packages of R?

Comment: @Kasper Van Lombeek  I agree.  I use `stringr` a lot

Comment: Does he actually really need an NA value?

Comment: Two additional methods if the NA value is unneeded: `gsub(".*(: [0-9]*)", "\\1", test[grep(": [0-9]*", test)])` and `unlist(regmatches(test, gregexpr(": [0-9]*", test)))`

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the contributions

Comment: @KasperVanLombeek Base R can do this, with the function `regmatches()`.  See the answer by @hwnd

Comment: @akrun, in the third method, what kind of construction do you use with //1? Is this the so called group operation? Thx

Comment: @Kasper Van Lombeek The contents inside the parentheses `(:.*)` are matched and a backreference `\\1` was used to substitute instead of the whole string `.*(:.*)`.  If there were two groups, it would have been `\\1 \\2` depending upon the desired output

Answer (score 8):

You can use base R which handles this just fine.

```
> x <- c('surface area: 458', 'bedrooms: 1', 'whatever')
> r <- regmatches(x, gregexpr(':.*', x))
> unlist({r[sapply(r, length)==0] <- NA; r})
# [1] ": 458" ": 1"   NA
```

Although, I find it much simpler to just do...

```
> x <- c('surface area: 458', 'bedrooms: 1', 'whatever')
> sapply(strsplit(x, '\\b(?=:)', perl=T), '[', 2)
# [1] ": 458" ": 1"   NA
```

Answer (score 4):

Try any of these.   The first two use the base of R only.  The last one assumes that we want to return a numeric vector.

**1) sub**

```
s <- sub(".*:", ":", test)
ifelse(test == s, NA, s)
## [1] ": 458" ": 1"   NA
```

If there can be more than one : in a string then replace the pattern with `"^[^:]*:"` .

**2) strsplit**

```
sapply(strsplit(test, ":"), function(x) c(paste0(":", x), NA)[2])
## [1] ": 458" ": 1"   NA
```

Do not use this one if there can be more than one : in a string.

**3) strapplyc**

```
library(gsubfn)
s <- strapplyc(test, "(:.*)|$", simplify = TRUE)
ifelse(s == "", NA, s)
## [1] ": 458" ": 1"   NA
```

We can omit the `ifelse` line if `""` is ok instead of `NA`.

**4) strapply**  If the idea is really that there are some digits on the line and we want to return the numbers or NA then try this:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapply(test, "\\d+|$", as.numeric, simplify = TRUE)
## [1] 458   1  NA
```